# Refinerycms-pages-images engine custom fields

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I'm using refinery CMS with the [refinierycms-blog](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-blog) and [refinerycms-pages-images](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-page-images) engines and I'd like to add a new custom field to each image (by default there is a caption field).

I've run a database migration so there is the a field on refinery_image_pages to hold the value, and edited refinery/admin/pages/tabs/_image_field.html.erb like so to show the field:

```
<%= text_field_tag "#{f.object_name.demodulize}[images_attributes][#{index}][image_margin_top]",
```

(`image_margin_top` being my custom field.)

My question is a two-parter:

1. How can I get the image_margin_top value to save to the db when submitting the blog edit form? I'm guessing I may need to edit one of the core models?
2. How can I display image_margin_top's value on the admin form? The default caption field uses a utility method in `_image_field.html.erb` -

   `f.object.caption_for_image_index(index)`

I'd like to create a `image_margin_top_for_image_index()` method but am not sure where to do so.

Many thanks